# I can't see QLabel and QLineEdit widgets in my QMainWindow in Python2

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyside, qlineedit, qlabel

I wrote this code and I don't understand why widgets QLabel and QLineEdit don't show up? Do I have to put them in another class? It's Python2.7 and PySide.

This is how a window looks like when I run the code:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import sys
import crypt
from PySide import QtGui

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initui()

    def initui(self):
        # main window size, title and icon
        self.setMinimumSize(500, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle("Calculate a password hash in Linux")

        # lines for entering data
        self.saltLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Salt:")
        self.saltLine = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.saltLine.setPlaceholderText("e.g. $6$xxxxxxxx")

        # set layout
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.saltLabel, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.saltLine, 1, 0)

        self.setLayout(grid)

        # show a widget
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    instance = MyApp()
    instance.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You don't need a `QMainWindow`. You should use a `QDialog` or simply a `QWidget`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a `QWidget` as `centralWidget`

```
widget = QWidget()
widget.setLayout(grid)
#add your widgets and...
self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

and you don't need to call `show()` since you do in your `__main__`

It's up to the owner but i would recommend sublassing a `QWidget` and leave your `QMainWindow` instance as concise as possible. An implementation could be:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        #and so on...
```

and use this as `widget` in your `QMainWindow` instance. This increases readability and maintainability and reusability a lot :)

Comment: Ok, when I do that (self not this), widgets do show but in top left corner, one over the other. However, I switched QMainWindow with QWidget and now it is ok. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the updated answer? `setCentralWidget` should fill your `QMainWindow` instance. Keep me updated if you won't get the upper example working. I can give a more detailed answer also.

Comment: I kept QMainWindow, added QLabel and QLineEdit widgets in grid and set widget as centrawidged in QMainWindow. It works, thanks!